# Code does not print arabic text from database

Tags: php, html, mysqli

The code below that I am using will not print text that is of arabic form from the database although the collation of the table is uft8_general_ci and the database is of collation uft8_general_ci.

code:

```
<?php

        // Create connection
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");
    mysqli_set_charset('utf8', $con);

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    // This SQL statement selects ALL from the table 'Locations'
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Mothakirat";
    mysqli_set_charset('utf8', $sql);

    // Check if there are results
    if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)) 
    {
        // If so, then create a results array and a temporary one
        // to hold the data
        $resultArray = array();
        $tempArray = array();

        // Loop through each row in the result set
        while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) 
        {
            // Add each row into our results array
            $tempArray = $row;
            array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
        }

        // Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
        echo htmlentities(json_encode($resultArray));
    }

    // Close connections
    mysqli_close($con);

?>​
```

How can I get the arabic to print properly?

Comment: what is it doing (and how confident are you of what is in the db)?

Comment: @jcuenod very confident, i have arabic text inside that isn't showing any ???? but when it prints to the page it shows ?????

Answer (score 0):

When working with non-Latin characters in a web based environment, I find there are three points of failure:

1) You need to tell mysql what output to give you when you connect (which you've already done, I think):

```
mysqli_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
```

2) You probably need to add

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

into the `<head>` section in your html.

3) You need to ensure that the font used to display the text has glyphs for the characters you are expecting to see (Times New Roman may not suffice). I have done stuff with Greek and Hebrew and I often find fonts have basic support but not when there are diacritics.

Comment: have you checked the html source that gets produced?

Comment: All those things need to be in place at once. Are you saying that there are question marks in your html? If so, the second two are irrelevant. The problem can only be with what's coming out of the db or the way you're printing it (or of course, what's in your database to begin with).

Comment: my database has only one column name. prints arabic names only.

Comment: @Sam sorry, I must admit I've revisited this a couple of times and there's nothing else I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

May be a long shot but have you checked the charset of the actual field?

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-column.html